# How to round a fraction into next digit using PHP

Tags: php, rounding

I know about php's built in `round()` function, which return `2` for `1.6`. But it return `1` for `1.1`. I want to return the next number if the given number has a fractional part. For example, I want to return `2` for `1.1`, or `1.01`, or even `1.0001`. But I don't want to return the same for `1.0`, which may return `1` itself. How can I achieve this in PHP?

Comment: you can't miss `ceil()` and `floor()` when you know about `round()`. `round()` is just hybrid(nearest integer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at php's [`ceil()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php).

```
echo ceil(4.3);    // 5
echo ceil(9.999);  // 10
echo ceil(-3.14);  // -3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ceil()` to round up to the next number

`echo ceil(1.0); // will echo 1`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php